# SSRS Multivalue parameter IN(@parameter)

Tags: reporting-services, server, report

Issue with commas in array field.
For starters: I have a column that has an array in it of varchars like this: `,901,902,` or `,901,906,902` or `,,,904,903`,
The `@parameter` I use to select this data needs to be multi-value but I cannot get this to work. The `@parameter` is named `@ArrayType` and uses values: `901` to `910`. 
The WHERE statement I use is this:

```
WHERE vendorContactTypeArray IN (@ArrayType)
```

However, the report fails because I do not know how to deal with splitting or dealing with commas in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN function to build multivalue parameter like this

```
=Join(Parameters!ParameterName.Value)
```

Comment: Ok, this works. But the result set is not right. The IN operator is acting like the AND operator because of the array in column. Is there a way around this? Currently, if I multi-select '901' and '902' the result set excludes single '901' results and only displays '901' and '902's.

Comment: Can you provide your entire query?